# Orient DB - Create dynamic edge

Tags: graph-theory, orientdb, edges

I have 2 classes, 1 is for medicines and other one is for monthly transactions. 
Structure for medicines:

```
Create class Medicines extends V
Create property Medicines.medicine_id integer
Create property Medicines.medicine_Brand integer
Create property Medicines.medicine_Code String
```

Structure for Monthly Transctions:

```
Create class Transactions extends V
Create property Transactions.transaction_id integer
Create property Transactions.transaction_Date Date
Create property Transactions. transaction _medicine_id Integer
```

Now here, I want create an edge that comesFrom "Transactions.transaction _medicine_id" to "Medicines.medicine_Code" . Incase of RDBMS, I would create a relation between “Transactions. transaction _medicine_Code” AND “Medicines.medicine_id” but in graph databases we cannot create relations between fields, so how should I create edge between these fields.

Medicines:

```
----+-----+---------+-----------+-------------
#   |@RID |@CLASS   |medicine_id|medicine_Code
----+-----+---------+-----------+-------------
0   |#15:0|Medicines|1          |abc
1   |#15:1|Medicines|2          |xyz
----+-----+---------+-----------+-------------
```

Transaction:

```
----+-----+------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------------
#   |@RID |@CLASS      |transaction_id|transaction_Date   |transaction_medicine_id
----+-----+------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------------
0   |#16:0|Transactions|1             |2016-01-12 00:00:00|1
1   |#16:1|Transactions|2             |2016-01-12 00:00:00|2
----+-----+------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------
```

--

What I want is an output like

```
----+-----+------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------------
#   |@RID |@CLASS      |transaction_id|transaction_Date   |transaction_medicine_Code|
----+-----+------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------------
0   |#16:0|Transactions|1             |2016-01-12 00:00:00|abc
1   |#16:1|Transactions|2             |2016-01-12 00:00:00|xyz
----+-----+------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------
```

--

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion you need to think more graphic db oriented, so removing the foreign key and making relations creating edges b/w medicines rids and transactions rids.

```
-----------         sell          --------------
|Medicines|  ----------------->   |Transactions|
-----------                       --------------


Create class Medicines extends V
Create property Medicines.medicine_Brand String
Create property Medicines.medicine_Code Integer

Create class Transactions extends V
Create property Transactions.transaction_id integer
Create property Transactions.transaction_Date Date


Create class sell extends E
```

then to obtain the requested output:

```
SELECT transaction_id, transaction_Date, in('sell').medicine_Code FROM Transactions
```